# Laravel session message as toastr notifications

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-4

How to convert the below session message to Toastr message without changing the controller code. In short i want to use toastr for all session messages without touching the controller code.

```
@if (session('status'))
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
     {{ session('status') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

I'm using basic bootstrap 4 and laravel 5.6

Comment: What have you tried? Also, `Toast` is a JS library; there shouldn't be any interaction with controller code anyway. You'd call this in a `<script>` within your `.blade.php` file, passing the text to the function with `'{{ session("status") }}'`

Comment: I have added this toastr to my laravel app "https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr" So do i need to add the javascript "toastr.info('Are you the 6 fingered man?')" as mentioned in their documentation between the if statement.

Comment: Yup, include it in the `@if(...)@endif` block within a `<script>` tag. Just have to make sure that `toastr` is included (`<script src="path/to/toastr.js"></script>`) *before* you include the snippet above.

Comment: Is this correct? "@if (session('status'))
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    toastr.info(session('status'))
                                </script>
                            @endif"

Comment: Almost, `session("status")` needs to be wrapped in `{{ }}` for `.blade.php` to convert it to a `string`. So `"{{ session('status') }}"`

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the same as answer so that i can accept and close this question. It's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `toastr` is a JS library, it needs to be included on the page calling the snippet (either on the same page or before a `.blade.php` directive such as `@include()` or `@yield()`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/toastr.js"></script>
```

Then, modify the snippet to use `toastr`:

```
@if(session("status"))
<script type="text/javascript">
  toastr.info("{{ session("status") }}");
<script>
@endif
```

`.blade.php` will convert `session("status")` to a `string`, which `toastr` will process and display as an `info` message.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Excellent response, helped a lot, Thank you. I added another answer with another need that I had in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Great response from friend [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis), but I faced yet another challenge for trying to use the toatsr from the AdminLte3 template automatically installed on Laravel 6.x.

Below what I did to complement and make it work in my project.

According to the [AminLte3 documentation](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/wiki/Usage), the additional inclusion of CSS or JS is through sections

Section example for adding CSS

```
@section('css')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin_custom.css">
@stop
```

Section example for adding JS

```
@section('js')
    <script> console.log('Hi!'); </script>
@stop
```

So I needed to add the Toastr library and then include my .blade file for alerts along with the JS section

JS section with the alerts .blade file

```
@section('js')
    <script src="myPath/toastr.js"></script>
    @include('myPath.alerts')
@stop
```

Alerts .blade file

```
@if(session("status"))
    <script type="text/javascript">
        toastr.info("{{ session("status") }}");
    <script>
@endif
```